# How to move an object with the mouse in Unity (2D)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d unity game for android. Please help me to implement mouse control (so that it can be controlled from the phone)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class qwe : MonoBehaviour
{
 public float direction = 1f; // initial direction
    public float speed = 20f; // speed of rotation

    void Update ()
    {
        float angle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
        if (angle > 180f) angle -= 360f;

        if ((angle < -40f) || (angle > 40f)) direction *= -1f; // reverse direction (toggles between 1 & -1)

        transform.Rotate (0, 0, speed * direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

To use mouse inputs you need to write

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    //your content here
}
```

Comment: which can **not** be controlled from the phone as requested in the question